# How to cancel AlarmClock that was created by my app?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am creating an app which intends to create an alarm just to wake up the user. I did **not** use the *AlarmManager* because I do not need the app to run any code or function once the alarm goes off. So, the end goal of my app is to set the phone's native alarm. For this, I used the *AlarmClock* class like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hour);
intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minute);
intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, false);
startActivity(intent);
```

I would like to have the functionality to cancel the alarm. How can I access the set alarms via the app code?

**Note:** The alarm does not show up in the alarm clock widget on the native home screen, but appears in the native *Clock* application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `AlarmClock` class doesn't expose a public action for this, there is no supported way to do this programmatically. The expectation is probably that users will do it via the UI. If you want more control, use `AlaramManager` and set/clear your own alarms.

Comment: That's strange. Why would they let you create alarms on the device but not cancel or edit them?

Comment: You don't create the alarm, just start a pre-populated screen that lets the user create one.

Comment: I see. Maybe I'll create my own alarm using the AlarmManager class then. Thanks for your answer.