# Android Alarm Clock - Remove alarms programmatically

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am writing an application in which user can configure alerts/alarms. At this point, I have everything working expect the one. I am firing off an alarm using

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
alarmIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Some message!");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);
context.startActivity(alarmIntent);
```

I want to remove this alarm once user has dismissed using the Dismiss button. I can see the alarms being still there in the alarm clock which I set using above code through my application.

Is there some way to get a cursor or something similar on the alarms being there in the alarm clock? This will help me iterate over them and remove the ones I want.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As it was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814658/how-to-cancel-alarmclock-that-was-created-by-my-app): there is no supported API to this.

[Official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html#ACTION_SET_ALARM) says that

> If a time of day is specified, and EXTRA_SKIP_UI is true, and the
>   alarm is not repeating, the implementation should remove this alarm
>   after it has been dismissed.

But different manufactures implement their own alarm clocks and I'm not sure if someone supporrts this. 
I have tried it on JB emulator and looks like it dosen't work. Maybe, on KitKat?
Only this one is ok on JB:

> If an identical alarm exists matching all parameters, the implementation
>   may re-use it instead of creating a new one

So, maybe, better solution is to use youre own alarm, created with AlarmManager or warn user that he has to remove Alarms by hands (to make it more obvious - not use AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI).

Answer (score 1):

call method `cancel(...)` from `AlarmManager`, using the same `PendingIntent` you used to set the alarm. Example:

```
mAlarmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, intent, flags);

this.getAlarmManager().cancel(mAlarmPendingIntent);
```

`this` refers to the `Activity` or the `Service` from which you are cancelling the alarm

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. However, I guess you need to go through my question once again. I am not asking for removing alarms from AlarmManager, I want to remove alarms set in Alarm Clock. Did I make it clear?

Comment: i dont understand what are you saying... as per your question, this is the answer. it also removed alarms which are set in alarm clock.