# How to stop AlarmClock in Android?

Tags: android, android-alarms

I want to use AlarmClock. I found the vendor and didn't know how to catch the event to stop an Alarm that is currently active. Any help?

```
PackageManager packageManager = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
                Intent alarmClockIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

                // Verify clock implementation
                String clockImpls[][] = {
                        {"HTC Alarm Clock", "com.htc.android.worldclock", "com.htc.android.worldclock.WorldClockTabControl" },
                        {"Standar Alarm Clock", "com.android.deskclock", "com.android.deskclock.AlarmClock"},
                        {"Froyo Nexus Alarm Clock", "com.google.android.deskclock", "com.android.deskclock.DeskClock"},
                        {"Moto Blur Alarm Clock", "com.motorola.blur.alarmclock",  "com.motorola.blur.alarmclock.AlarmClock"},
                        {"Samsung Galaxy Clock", "com.sec.android.app.clockpackage","com.sec.android.app.clockpackage.ClockPackage"},
                        {"Standar Alarm Clock2", "com.google.android.deskclock", "com.android.deskclock.AlarmClock"},
                        { "Sony Ericsson Xperia Z", "com.sonyericsson.organizer", "com.sonyericsson.organizer.Organizer_WorldClock" }
                };

                boolean foundClockImpl = false;

                for(int i=0; i<clockImpls.length; i++) {
                    String vendor = clockImpls[i][0];
                     packageName = clockImpls[i][1];
                     className = clockImpls[i][2];
                    try {
                        ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(packageName, className);
                        ActivityInfo aInfo = packageManager.getActivityInfo(cn, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                        alarmClockIntent.setComponent(cn);
                        Log.e(" --> "+vendor , "---->"+ packageName + className);
                        foundClockImpl = true;
                    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                        Log.e(""+vendor , " does not exists");
                    }
                }

                if (foundClockImpl) {


                           // what can i do here ???

                }
```

Comment: try out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16999419/2737421