# How to cancel specific Alarm in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

In my app, the user can set multiple alarms for the same movie e.g "On release date", "A week before release", "A month before release" and now I'm stuck on cancelling a specific alarm, I know how to cancel an alarm with and movie id, but how to I cancel it with the movie id and the type. do I concatenate both together and pass it as the id to my pending intent?

Code:

```
    public void cancelAlarm(Context context, _Alarm alarm) {
    //Log.d(TAG, "{cancelAlarm}");
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, (int) alarm.getGameId(), intent, 0);
    alarmManager.cancel(alarmIntent);
}
```

Alarm class has the id of the movie and the type of the alarm

Comment: you will find your answer here [duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999343/android-alarm-clock-remove-alarms-programmatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> do I concatenate both together and pass it as the id to my pending
>   intent?

It seems logical.

Also you can use below way to know if your PendingIntent exists.

```
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode,
          intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
if (broadcast != null) {
    alarmManager.cancel(alarmIntent );
}
```