# Using AlarmManager Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, repeatingalarm

I am working on an android app and I am setting an alarm using the following code:

`Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
    i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, 0);
    i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, 0);`

It works, but how can I deactivate this alarm?

Comment: pls post your code including pendingIntent or how you set the alarm, its not just Intent i... right?

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
             i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, 0);
             i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, 0);
             i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
             context.startActivity(i);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814658/how-to-cancel-alarmclock-that-was-created-by-my-app

Answer (score 0):

try this code..,may be it helps you.

```
 buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

 @Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
  MyScheduledReceiver.class);

 PendingIntent pendingIntent
= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),
   0, myIntent, 0);

 AlarmManager alarmManager
 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

 alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setClass(MyScheduledActivity.this,
  AndroidScheduledActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
  finish();
}});
```

here you can use pending intent for stopping alarm.